# Powershell copy-item then test-path or copy-item with catch?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that moves files around in a production environment and currently performs a copy-item, then test-path, followed by remove-item if the test-path worked ok, similar to the below:

```
if ($copySuccess -eq $true) {
    $files = Get-ChildItem $fileDir -Filter $filePrefix*.*
    $files | ForEach-Object {
        if ($copySuccess -eq $true) {
            Copy-Item $fileDir\$_ -Destination $destDir
            if (!(Test-Path $destDir\$_)) {
                $copySuccess = $false
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

This method makes me feel comfortable as the test-path guarantees that the file is where it needs to be, before removing it.

I'm planning to rewrite parts of the script and I'm wondering if by using a copy-item with a catch on error, I can be sure that if no error is seen that the file has definitely been copied to the destination (without the need to use test-path as I assume this would make it quicker).  As in below:

```
Get-ChildItem $fileDir -Filter $filePrefix*.* | ForEach {
    if ($copySuccess -eq $true) {
        try {
            Copy-Item $fileDir\$_ -Destination $destDir -ErrorAction Stop
            }
        catch {
              $copySuccess = $false
              } 
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if there is a better way, please let me know (Powershell v5).  The reason for this level of checking is that there are often network issues on the infrastructure, hence the test-path currently in use.

Comment: The first "if ($copySuccess = $true)" should be "if ($copySuccess -eq $true)" or better: if ($copySuccess)

Comment: Ahh well spotted, that was just a typo, it is -eq but I'm rushing and not copy+pasting.  Good thought regarding if($copySuccess) though, thanks.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use Move-Item?

Comment: As the infrastructure can be 'temperamental', I've always opted to copy first, then check it is in the destination, before then using remove-item.  Just in case something happens with connectivity during the move.  As I say, perhaps this is overkill and would greatly appreciate a steer on a better way, or if move-item will never lose a file and can be used.

Comment: @RobBerry Think about, what _"moving an item"_ is. It's copying, then removing an item. If it can't be written, why should it be removed at the target?

Answer (score 2):

`ErrorAction` won't work in this case since:

> The `ErrorAction` parameter has no effect on terminating errors (such as
>   missing data, parameters that are not valid, or insufficient
>   permissions) that prevent a command from completing successfully.
>   [[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315352.aspx)]

If you want to check whether Copy-Item worked you can do this in a couple of ways to make sure.

The first one is to use `$?` variable:

> Errors and Debugging: The success or failure status of the last
>   command can be determined by checking $?

```
Copy-Item $fileDir\$_ -Destination $destDir
if(-not $?) {
    Write-Warning "Copy Failed"
}
```

Another method is by using the `-Passthru` parameter, we can capture the results to a variable.  Note, this variable will only be populated if the operation was successful:

```
if(-not Copy-Item $fileDir\$_ -Destination $destDir -PassThru) {
    Write-Warning "Copy Failed"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I wasn't aware of these other options.  I'm assuming that the first method would be preferred (and presumably faster than test-path)?  I'll give them a try now.